# the correct approach of connecting a hash of array to another hash of hash

Tags: perl

I have a hash structure, where each key corresponds to a "value", which is an array. I defined and constructed this hash structure as follows:

```
my %app
push @{$app{$id}}, $id;
```

I am trying to make this hash structure to be indexed by another hash structure,

```
my %chainro
```

which itself is a hash of hash.  It looks like there have three different approaches to connect these two structure, I am not sure which one is correct.

```
$chainro{$ro}{$id} = $app{$id}

@{$chainro{$ro}{$id}} = @{$app{$id}}

$chainro{$ro} = \%app;
```

Comment: What's this: `push @{$app{$id}}, $id` ? Is that a typo? It makes no sense to use the same variable for key **and** value in a hash.

Answer (score 2):

The last one:

```
my %app
push @{$app{$id}}, $id;
$chainro{$ro} = \%app;
```

And you can then access an element:

```
$chainro{$ro}->{$id}->[$index]
```

The `->` are needed when you are accessing a hash or array using a reference rather than the hash or array itself.

Comment: Missing semicolon after first line, should by "my %app;"

Comment: Dan, thanks. To assessing an element, why cannot use $chainro->{$ro}->{$id}->[$index]

Comment: Because `%chainro` is a hash and `$chainro` does not exist. If you wish to use `$chainro->stuff`, then `$chainro` must be a reference. For example you can say `$chainro = \%chainro` and then the expression you gave would be valid.

Comment: Dan thanks. Can you elaborate more on why $chainro{$ro}{$id} = $app{$id} and @{$chainro{$ro}{$id}} = @{$app{$id}} are not right?